# What is the difference between different input/output redirection styles?

Tags: linux, bash

What are the differences between these commands:

1. `command 2>&1 > log`
2. `command > log 2>&1`
3. `command >& log`
4. `command > log 1>&2`

First one outputting the error to the console and, the output to the log. Why not both doesn't go to the log?

Second one doesn't produce any output, the output and the error are in the in the log. What difference it makes to put `2>&1` at the end?

Third one is same as previous. For what is it a shortcut?

Fourth one puts everything to console and nothing to the log?

example command : `ls -ld /tmp /xxx`

Comment: IMHO case #2 and #4 is identical, isn't it?

Comment: @TrueY No. #2 lets 2 point to 1, #4 lets 1 point to 2.

Comment: @glglgl: After modification of the Q. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are very well explained in [two](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/055) [articles](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FileDescriptor). Essentially, you have to read the redirects from left to right as *copies* of an output target. So

```
command 2>&1 > log
```

1. Sets the target of FD 2 (standard error) to the target of FD 1 (standard output), which is usually the terminal.
2. Sets the target of FD 1 to the file `log`.

These are not transitive, so standard error really points to the terminal when the command runs.

---

```
command > log 2>&1
```

1. Sets the target of FD 1 to the file `log`.
2. Sets the target of FD 2 (standard error) to the target of FD 1 (standard output), which now is the file `log`.

This means both standard output and standard error are logged to the same file.

---

```
command >& log
```

Redirects both standard error and standard output to the file `log`. This is Bash syntactic sugar for the previous command.

---

```
command > log 1>&2
```

1. Sets the target of FD 1 to the file `log`.
2. Sets the target of FD 1 to target of FD 2 (standard error), which is usually the terminal. This overrides the previous redirection.

Answer (score 2):

The redirection order is important in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

1. `command 2>&1 > log` redirects `stderr` to `stdout` and then `stdout` to log file. So the result is `stderr` goes to the screen (if not redirected on some higher level) and `stdout` goes to file.
2. `command > log 2>&1` redirects `stdout` to a file, and the `stderr` redirected to the file handle `1` which is the file.
3. `command >&log` is the shortcut for the previous case, namely it redirects `stderr` and `stdout` to the file.
4. This it the same case as #2
5. `command > log 1>&2` redirects `stderr` (file handle 1) to a file, then it redirects it to `stderr`. So as a result `stdout` will go to `stderr`. But a zero byte long `log` file appears. This can be written as `command >log >&2`.